# WFS height/extrusion in OL3 cesium

Tags: openlayers, wfs, cesium

I am making a web application with OL3 and have integrated a 3d viewer with cesium. I have two data sets that are being loaded with GeoJSON as vector WFS. Both data sets have height information contained and are published as such in GeoServer (Elevation is set).

I am trying to give one WFS an extrusion (building locations) and the other a height (aircraft elevation). Everything I have found seems to be based off of cesium geometry. Is it possible to do this? Do I need to convert to primitives first?

** EDIT **
Here is the buildingSource script:

```
var geojsonFormat2 = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var buildingSource = new ol.source.Vector({ 
    loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
    var url = 'http://local:58088/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
    'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=Thunderbirds:Nevada&' +
    'outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures2' +
    '&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: true
    }).done(function(response) {
        WFSformat = new ol.format.WFS(),
        sourceVector.addFeatures(WFSformat.readFeatures(response)) }); },
strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
    maxZoom: 19 })) });
```

Comment: So do you want to make a spatial query on client. I mean using the geometry from one layer to select features from other layer? Or do you want to make a wfs request to your backend server for the selection?

Comment: Neither, I am not trying to make a selection. I am just trying to display both point datasets at the same time in a 3D scene.

Comment: Hi @alex89. I know this been a while since you posted this question, but i was wondering if you could upload the entire script and not only the buildingSource script? I am trying to setup my own WFS source for an OL3+cesium project.

Answer (score 1):

Load the [GeoJSON Sandcastle Demo](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=GeoJSON%20and%20TopoJSON.html&label=Showcases) and click the `Custom styling` button in the top of the 3D window.  The code on the left shows how the GeoJSON is being assigned extrusion heights.

Once the dataSource has (asynchronously) loaded, a for-loop iterates over all the entities in the dataSource, and in this example assigns `entity.polygon.extrudedHeight` based on population.  You can assign any property you like to be the extruded height value here.

You can also assign `entity.polygon.height` for the ones where you want altitude but not extrusion.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful, but I have a question.  Both of my data sets are points. How do I convert them to circle so that I can extrude (so far I haven't found anything for point extrusion/height)

Comment: Also, I keep getting a 'buildingSource.entities is undefined' error. Can I not use a data source defined in ol3?

Comment: I don't know much about OL3, can you post the code that creates `buildingSource`?  Also there's no extrusion for a point, but you could create a [polyline](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/PolylineCollection.html?classFilter=polyline) from the ground to the building height.

Comment: Edited in original question  
Right, but wouldn't using a circle geometry be easier?

Comment: Sure, circle geometry works too.  Looks like `buildingSource` is an OL3 object, I don't know OL3 well enough to know how to get the Cesium entities out of that object.  I see there's an [applyHeightOffsetToGeometry](http://openlayers.org/ol3-cesium/apidoc/olcs.core.html#.applyHeightOffsetToGeometry) function, but I don't know if you can get finer-grained access to the underlying Cesium objects.